# Invalid cast exception on remote server Guid to string

Tags: asp.net

I have this code in my project:

```
string userId = Membership.GetUser(username).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_Membership SET IsLockedOut = 0, LastLockoutDate = @LastLockedOutDate WHERE UserId = @Userid", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastLockedOutDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = userId;
int rowsAffected = 0;
conn.Open();
rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This works fantastic on my local machine. The user gets unlocked no problem. But for some reason when I deploy it to a demo site on the remote server I get this error:

```
InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a String
```

It's failing on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery line. I tried changing the parameter to a uniqueidentifier and passing the actual guid but that didn't work either.

Anybody know why this would work locally but not on a remote server? Or know of a way I can modify the code to possibly work?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to manually unlock the user could you not use :-

```
 var oUser = Membership.GetUser(username);
 oUser.UnlockUser();
 Membership.UpdateUser(oUser);
```

This allows the .NET process to do all the heavy lifting for you.

[Edit to answer the original question]

```
        Guid gUserID = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(username).ProviderUserKey;
        if (gUserID != Guid.Empty)
        {
            using (
                var oConn =
                    new SqlConnection(connectionString)
            {
                oConn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE aspnet_Membership SET IsLockedOut = 0, LastLockoutDate = @LastLockedOutDate WHERE UserId = @gUserID";
                    oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@gUserID", gUserID));
                    oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastLockedOutDate", DateTime.UtcNow));
                    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

It may also be worth changing your DateTime.Now to DateTime.UtcNow so that if you ever have to move timezones or share with other machines out of your location you are all on a equivilent time.

If you get an error thrown on the ProviderUserKey then chances are either the user doesn't exist or the UserID isn't a GUID after all.

Comment: Actually I can't. The person before me created a custom membership provider because they decided to add a couple columns to aspnet_membership. This code is in the custom provider.

Comment: How exactly does that differ from my implementation? Won't I still get the conversion error?

Comment: Your currently converting it from a Guid, to a string, then to variable length string in SQL to a UUID. This doesn't do any conversions just straight out casts it as a Guid.

Comment: I tried that when I was testing Francois answer. Didn't work. Looking at the code I might be able to rip out the custom provider which would solve my issue. Let's hope that works.

Comment: If you can't rip out the custom provider, maybe remove the UnlockUser override, or just call the base UnlockUser function? Good luck! Forgot to add, Francois B's answer still has a conversion (string->guid) in it. Might be worth giving it a shot with a straight casting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Userid", SqlDbType.Guid).Value = new Guid(userId);`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lame answering my own question but I resolved this. I stripped the custom membership provider out and just used the default membershipUser.UnlockUser(); and it works great. The custom provider wasn't actually doing anything anyway. I think it was developed for features that aren't being used anymore.